# извлечение данных через intent putextra

Tags: android-intent

есть 2 Activity,хочу из первого Activity list View через intent  передать во 2 Activity данные реализовал таким методом :

```html
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, about.class);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
            intent.putExtra("key1", getResource().getString(R.string.tekst1));
            break;
            case 1:
            intent.putExtra("ke2", getResource().getString(R.string.tekst2));
            break ;
            case 2:
            intent.putExtra("key3", getResource ().getString(R.string.tekst3));
            break ;
        }
        startActivity (intent) ;
    }
});
```

а вот так пытался во втором активити  излечь

```html
TextView textView = (TextView) findbyiD(R.id.textview);
String tekst =getIntent().getExtras().getString("key1");
switch(i){
case 0:
TextView.setText(key1)
case1:
break;

textview.setText(key2)
case2:
break;

texView.setTex(key3)
break;
```

не могу извлечь знаю что извлчеание неправильное скок посмотрел офф документацию не смог ,кому не сложно помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для запаковки используй одинаковый ключ. А в другом извлекай:

textView.setText(getIntent()getStringExtra("ключ"));
И не проще использовать OnclickListener?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [OmegaIntentBuilder](https://github.com/Omega-R/OmegaIntentBuilder) с кодогенерацией:

```
@OmegaActivity
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

@OmegaExtra("key")
String text

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        AppOmegaIntentBuilder.inject(this);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textView.setText(text);
    }

}
```

Запустить интент:

```
AppOmegaIntentBuilder.from(this)
                .appActivity()
                .exampleActivity()
                .key("Your text here")
                .createIntentHandler()
                .startActivity();
```